# Custom Div Scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML markup and CSS (http://jsfiddle.net/7zo4Lch5/3/).

```
 <div class="div_top_view">
      <div class="div_top_left">
        <div class="div_left_menu">
          <p>Left Menu</p>
          <p>Left Menu</p>
          <p>Left Menu</p>
          <p>Left Menu</p>
          <p>Left Menu</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="div_top_right">
        <img class="img" src="http://worldartsme.com/images/sheet-of-paper-clipart-1.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div_divider">
    </div>
    <div class="div_bottom_view">
      <p>Bottom View</p>
    </div>
```

As you can see a scroll bar appears to the right of "div_top_view".
This scroll bar scrolls both "div_top_left" and "div_top_right".

I want a scroll bar on "div_top_left" and another one "div_top_right" if needed, to scroll each div independently.
How can that be accomplished?

Also, "div_top_right" has a large image in it. It needs a vertical and a horizontal scroll bar. The horizontal scroll bar only appears when you scroll all the way to the bottom.
How can I have this horizontal scrollbar be always visible?

Comment: when I view your fiddle there is no scroll bar anywhere.

Comment: @JulianSilvestri - https://imgur.com/a/WE9KfyC

Comment: Ah you know what it is, I am on a MAC lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution does not require flexbox but does require changing your html.
Currently your first div:  `<div class="div_top_view">` has the top right and the top left view nested within it. This is what is preventing you from achieving the seperate scroll function. 
Check the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="div_top_view">
      <div class="div_top_left">
        <div class="div_left_menu">
          <p>Left Menu</p>
          <p>Left Menu</p>
          <p>Left Menu</p>
          <p>Left Menu</p>
          <p>Left Menu</p>
          <p>Left Menu</p>
          <p>Left Menu</p>
          <p>Left Menu</p>
          <p>Left Menu</p>
          <p>Left Menu</p>
          <p>Left Menu</p>
          <p>Left Menu</p>
          <p>Left Menu</p>
          <p>Left Menu</p>
          <p>Left Menu</p>
          <p>Left Menu</p>
          <p>Left Menu</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="div_top_view2">
            <div class="div_top_right">
        <img class="img" src="http://worldartsme.com/images/sheet-of-paper-clipart-1.jpg" />
      </div>

      </div>

    <div class="div_divider">
    <span>I am in the divider and should not have this div here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="div_bottom_view">
      <p>Bottom View</p>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

All i did was create a new class for the top right portion.
Giving the top right a fixed height solves your issue for a horizontally visible scroll bar. 
I also gave the top right div absolute positioning and fixed it to the top right of the screen.
Additionally i also changed the top left div to have a width of 50%
check code below:

```
.div_top_view2 {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  height: 50%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: visible;
  width:50%;
}

.div_top_right {
  width: auto;
  /*max-width: 1000px;*/
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
  /*overflow: auto;*/
}

.div_top_view {
  position: relative;
  height: 50%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Check fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7zo4Lch5/57/

I hope this is what you are looking for!

All the best :)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Excellent!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is one word: **flexbox**.

I removed all your float and put `.div_top_view {display:flex;}`. I added `flex:0 1 100px;` and an `overflow-y:scroll` in .`div_top_left` and `flex:1;` in `.div_top_right`and flexbox does the charm. :)

PS. I changed your img (not its dimentions) 'cause I have trouble to display it in this snippet. Sorry.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.div_top_view {
  position: relative;
  height: 50%;
  display:flex;
  /*overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;*/
}

.div_top_right {
  flex:1;
 /* width: auto;
  max-width: 1000px;*/
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /*overflow: auto;*/
}

.div_divider {
  height: 1px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: black;
}

.div_bottom_view {
  position: relative;
  height: 50%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.div_top_left {
  flex:0 1 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.div_left_menu {
  width: 70px;
}

.img {
  height: auto;
  /*transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: bottom left;*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="div_top_view">
      <div class="div_top_left">
        <div class="div_left_menu">
          <p>Left Menu</p>
          <p>Left Menu</p>
          <p>Left Menu</p>
          <p>Left Menu</p>
          <p>Left Menu</p>
          <p>Left Menu</p>
          <p>Left Menu</p>
          <p>Left Menu</p>
          <p>Left Menu</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="div_top_right">
        <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/1855/2400" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div_divider">
    </div>
    <div class="div_bottom_view">
      <p>Bottom View</p>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```